# Derivations of operation, operable vs. reparation, reparable

Tags: etymology, latin, derivational-morphology

After a little thought I decided *irreparable* derives from *repairable*, but a few seconds later, decided it stems from *reparation*, "like *operable* from *operation*".  Looking the words up, I found I was wrong about both derivations:

[*Reparation* and *reparable*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=repara) derive from L. *reparatus*, pp. of *reparare* "restore", (ca. 1400 and 1570, resp.) rather than one from the other.

For [*operable*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=operab) and [*operation*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=operat) the story seems a bit different, with *operable* deriving in the 1640s from operate + -able and *operation* (late 1300's) from L. *operationem*, from pp. stem of *operari*.

What are the names of the processes by which these words derived from Latin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you are interpreting those entries on Etymology.com the right way.

The Latin verb *reparare* ("to repair"), stem *repara-*, acquired the adjective ***reparabilis*** ("repairable"), regularly formed by the suffix *-bilis* in classical Latin. This then changed in French, a language which evolved naturally from Latin, into *reparable* during the 16th century. English borrowed this word again from French.

The past participle of *reparare* was regularly formed in classical Latin as *reparatus* ("[having been] repaired"), stem *reparat-*. In Late Latin, the action noun ***reparatio*** ("the repairing") was regularly formed from this by adding the action suffix *-io*, stem *-ion-*. The stem of this new action noun was (regularly) *reparation-*. In the 14th century, this word was borrowed by English (I suspect that it was also borrowed through French, but it doesn't say so).

The etymology of *operable* and *operation* is similar. Latin *operari*, stem *opera-*, leads to adjective ***operabilis*** (it doesn't say whether this word was actually formed in classical Latin, or in later Latin, or only hypothetically in successor languages), borrowed as *operable* in English ca. 1640.

Past participle stem *opera-t-*, leads to action noun ***operatio*** in Latin, borrowed/changed by French as *operacion*, borrowed by English from French as *operation* in the late 14th century.

Comment: So the names of the processes involved would be "leading to" and "borrowing"?

Comment: @Tao: I'd say suffigation (adding a suffix) and borrowing.